# Повреждение apt при установке Chrome

Tags: ubuntu, google-chrome, apt-get

Делал всё по статье http://www.linuxrussia.com/2014/06/google-chrome-ubuntu.html и очень сильно пожалел. И chrome не установился, и теперь при попытке установить любое ПО такая картина:

```
avs@vaio-pc:/$ sudo apt-get install tasksel
Чтение списков пакетов… Готово
Построение дерева зависимостей       
Чтение информации о состоянии… Готово
Возможно, для исправления этих ошибок вы захотите воспользоваться «apt-get -f install»:
Пакеты, имеющие неудовлетворённые зависимости:
 google-chrome-stable : Зависит: libappindicator1 но он не будет установлен
 tasksel : Зависит: tasksel-data но он не будет установлен
E: Неудовлетворённые зависимости. Попытайтесь выполнить «apt-get -f install», не указывая имени пакета, (или найдите другое решение).
avs@vaio-pc:/$
```

Comment: а какая у Вас ОС ? Ubuntu ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt-get update
```

А теперь можно и `sudo apt-get -f install`

Comment: Реакция на autoremove
avs@vaio-pc:/$ sudo apt-get autoremove
Чтение списков пакетов… Готово
Построение дерева зависимостей       
Чтение информации о состоянии… Готово
Возможно, для исправления этих ошибок вы захотите воспользоваться «apt-get -f install».
Пакеты, имеющие неудовлетворённые зависимости:
 google-chrome-stable : Зависит: libappindicator1 но он не установлен
E: Неудовлетворённые зависимости. Попытайтесь использовать -f.

Comment: @Viacheslav, выполните команды по-порядку, сделайте скрин терминала.

Comment: http://www.picshare.ru/view/7811854/

Comment: пробовал удалять репозиторий гугла(средствами графического меню ubuntu), это ничего не меняло

Comment: @Viacheslav, так, а когда вводите sudo apt-get -f install ? Не увидел на скрине.

Comment: Да забыл про sudo apt-get -f install , нужно было внимательней смотреть, помогло.

Comment: @Viacheslav, если Вам помогло - отметьте, пожалуйста, ответ как верный.

Comment: Извиняюсь, но как тут отмечать, не могу сориентироваться

Comment: @Viacheslav, галочка рядом с ответом. Ничего страшного )

Comment: понял, теперь зелёная

Answer (score 0):

Возникла похожая проблема, только разве Chrome установится. Решил следующим способом: установил то, на отсутствие чего он жаловался `sudo apt install -f libappindicator3-1`. Далее все пакеты устанавливались обычным `sudo apt install` без параметра `-f`. Взято [отсюда](https://forum.ubuntu.ru/index.php?topic=308856.0).